# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine - Elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch on my localhost was working fine. But today morning When I started the system, it was not working... Can anyone help me with

What could be causing the problem?

`systemctl status elasticsearch.service` shows this

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-13 10:30:42 IST; 16s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 5857 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5857 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:119)
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:81)
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:38)
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:135)
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd-entrypoint[5988]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 13 10:30:42 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Comment: did you change jvm.option? please share /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option

Comment: I am not able to update my answer with jvm.options as stackoverflow not allowing me, says my question contains almost code... my heap is set to 4gb, here from hvm.options : ## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g